# ASP.Net MVC 3 - Dynamically compiled assembly used as a model in a custom virtual path provider view

Tags: .net, dynamic, razor, assemblies

I have a setup where MVC model classes are being built on the fly in the controller serving the request via the CodeDomProvider as in the following code:

```
//model source is properly structured C# code
CodeDomProvider cdProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

            CompilerParameters cParams = new CompilerParameters();
            cParams.GenerateInMemory = false;
            cParams.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
            cParams.WarningLevel = 4;
            cParams.OutputAssembly = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), modelNamespace+".dll");


            cParams.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(modelFrameworkReferences.ToArray());

            try
            {
                CompilerResults cResults = cdProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cParams, modelSource);
             modelAssembly = cResults.CompiledAssembly;
             // omitted for brevity....
            }
```

This works fine and the model gets generated (and cached for later use) and then an instance of it is created via modelAssembly.CreateInstance.

The project also uses a custom VirtualPathProvider and VirtualFile implementation to serve Razor view mark-up out of some external storage. The retrieval part works fine, but when the Razor view is being compiled by the framework, the compilation fails because the view references a type in the dynamically generated assembly.

Reviewing the view compilation commandline to the csc.exe reveals that the reference to the dynamically generated library is not included in the command line even though the generated assembly is loaded in the appdomain (verified by listing the assemblies) and the view mark-up contains the proper @using directive referencing the namespace of the generated assembly.

Is there something that can be done to ensure that the dynamically generated assembly types are being referenced for view compilation?

I understand that I can use the dynamic model approach and that I can have all dynamically generated model classes derive from a pre-defined (non-dynamic) interface which the views can reference, but for various reasons I would like to have a reference to the dynamically generated model itself.